# Implementing an AVL tree somehow unable to print all the nodes with inorder traversal

Tags: c++, debugging, implementation, avl-tree

My implementation of insertion into the AVL_tree:

```
void AVL_Tree::insert(const Tree & x, avl_node* & t){
  //cout << "in avltree insert with 2 param" << endl;
  if(t == NULL){ //empty tree or does not exist in tree
    //cout << "adding new node" << endl;
    avl_node* p = new avl_node(x, NULL, NULL, 0);
    t = p;
    ++size;
    cout << "added new node success" << endl;
  }
  else if(x < t->element){
    cout << " x < t element" << endl;
    insert(x, t->left);
    cout << "inserted LEFT" << endl;
    if((get_height(t->left))-(get_height(t->right)) == 2){ //balance factor = 2
      if(x < t->left->element){ //inserted to the left subtree of the left child
        LL_rotation(t);
        cout << "LL rotation" << endl;
      }
      else{ //inserted to the right subtree of the left child
        LR_rotation(t);
        cout << "LR rotation" << endl;
      }
    }
  }
  else if(t->element < x){
    cout << " x > t eleemtn " << endl;
    insert(x, t->right);
    cout << "inserted RIGHT" << endl;
    if((get_height(t->right))-(get_height(t->left)) == 2){  //balance factor = 2
      if(t->right->element < x){ //inserted into the right subtree of the right child
        RR_rotation(t);
        cout << "RR rotation" << endl;
      }
      else{ //inserted into the left subtree of the right child
        RL_rotation(t);
        cout << "RL rotation" << endl;
      }
    }
  }
  else{ //duplicate; do not need to insert into tree
    cout << " duplicate? " << endl;
    ;
    t->height = max(get_height(t->left), get_height(t->right)) + 1; //saves the height of the AVL tree after insertion
  }
```

}

My print function that does an in-order traversal of the AVL Tree:

```
void AVL_Tree::print (ostream & out, avl_node* t) const{
      if(t != NULL){
    print(out, t->left);
    out << t->element << endl;
    print(out, t->right);
  }
}
```

I have 99 nodes but somehow when I print only about 10 of the nodes print. I believe the insertion works properly because the size of the tree is 99. Am I missing something in the code to traverse the AVL for printing?

Comment: Debugging recursive code and structures is a hassle, but it's still something that needs to be done from time to time. So please [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Not to mention AVL and Red-Black tree rotations can be done with wildly different implementations. Suggest you work through the link above and don't discount your talk with the duck...